# How to prevent a servlet from buffering response content

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient, outputstream, buffering

I have a servlet that writes bytes to its outputstream. The size of the content might be large. I want to prevent the servlet from doing any buffering. 
What is the best way to prevent response buffering? I do not want to call flush() or close() on the ServletOutputStream myself as I assume the servlet container should do that for me.
In that case, where do the bytes reside if the servlet calls flush() and close() and the httpclient hasn't yet read the bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every servlet container provides behind-the-scene implementations of the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse implementations meaning that you have no idea if the backing impl inside of one container buffers the writes and the other doesn't.

That said, the buffering will be limited to a small multi-KB size (if it is even done) so you can simply write() over and over and over again to the output stream without worrying about memory. The impl will stream those bytes to the network connection, over the wire, to the client where it is the job of the network hardware, operating system and client code to buffer and read all the content.

TCP will take care of ACKs and resending any lost data for you automatically.

In short, you don't need to worry about the client "Catching up"; just write out your data and everything on the clients end in combination with TCP will take care of getting the data there.

Comment: Thanks.. I still wonder where the bytes go after flush is called.. are they buffered on the client?

Comment: They are pushed to your OS's network stack so now your OS's TCP/IP network code is responsible for ensuring the client receives all that data (your send buffer). There is also buffering on your network hardware itself, then there is buffering on the client side at all those levels at all. It is a level of complexity that intelligent network protocol design allows us to ignore when we write network code fortunately.

Comment: Awesome.. so I guess the answer is a close() and flush() on the ServletOutputstream is all thats needed to ensure no buffering takes place on the server and most Servlet containers close and flush for you so that you don't even need to do it yourself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will want to do the flush() first (to force any bytes out of any buffers -- if any -- into the network stream) then close() to terminate the connection. If you close() first and there are bytes pending, they die all alone in the buffer and never get sent out to the client. But yes, you are right, you don't need to worry about buffering, the server will do the right thing.